# Inner join query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I'm trying to develop a student information system. In this system I want to show student's classes and instructors in the student's profile page, and I couldn't write the correct Inner Join  query. These are my tables;

```
Students
id
name
last_name
major
faculty
classes

Instructors
ID
name
last_name
major

Classes
class_id
class_name
class_faculty
instructor // Here I have the instructor who teaches that class
student  // Here I have the student who takes that class
```

Comment: Does the `student` field in the Classes table store a student ID? What does `instructor` store? We need more information about your tables and data structure.

Comment: No ID in the instructors table?

Comment: Your schema implies that each class has only one instructor (normal) and one student (probably not). You need an additional "join table" with class_id and student_id to allow a 1-N relationship.

Comment: @NateBarbettini I store the student id in the Classes table. Instructors table only stores the teachers information.

Comment: I think that is the answer @jcaron!. I'm new in programming, so I will make a research for 1-N relationship and join table. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jcaron is right: you need an additional table that represents students that have signed up for classes.

```
Students
id
name
last_name
major

Instructors
ID
name
last_name
major

Classes
class_id
class_name
class_faculty
instructor_id

StudentRegistrations
student_id
class_id
```

Then you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM StudentRegistrations reg
INNER JOIN Students ON Students.id = reg.student_id
INNER JOIN Classes ON Classes.class_id = reg.class_id
INNER JOIN Instructors ON Instructors.ID = Classes.instructor_id
```

Comment: Yes. that's the answer. Thanks Nate. I'll edit the tables, and use the query that you mentioned.

Comment: @BurakErgenc Great. Let me know if the query works correctly - I wrote it off the top of my head and didn't test. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is how i think your database should be designed:

[image]

And this is the SQL query that you need:

```
select 
    c.name, 
    t.firstname
from 
    class_has_student cs
inner join 
    class c 
    on cs.class_id = c.id
inner join 
    teacher t 
    on c.teacher_id = t.id
where 
    cs.student_id = 1
```

You have to replace the '1' with the 'id' of the current student profile.